# Import Qt Creator project from mac into windows - How to get UI informations?

Tags: windows, macos, qt, qt-creator

i developed a qt-project on Qt Creator for Mac OS. Now i want to import this projekt on Windows (Qt Creator, Compiler, libs are already installed).

Compiling the project already works. But when running, it crashes. On Mac I changed some classes in the UI (Qt Creator). So I did the same on Windows. But it still crashes. I also tried to copy the **ui_mainwindow.h** from Mac to Windows. Doesn't work.

I remembered, that I added some slots in the UI (Qt Creator) to make buttons functional. And only the mainwindow.h and mainwindow.cpp changed (in my gitHub version). But usually you have to add connect(SIGNAL ... SLOT ...) to add functionality to Buttons. So I searched for this functions, and found their names in **moc_mainwindow.cpp**

And this **moc_mainwindow.cpp** file is also on windows, but contains different stuff (not my in Mac UI added slots). And when copying my project from Mac to Window the folder doesn't contain **moc_mainwindow.cpp**. So it has to be build by the system.

Does anybody know how to get the SLOT information from my Mac project to the **moc_mainwindow.cpp** on Windows. And is the changing of this file enough or do I have to change also other files to get my project work on Windows?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to run `qmake` on the `.pro` file and run make on the generated files

in qCreator you can do this in the build menu